# Expected 'TypeCheckingMode.SKIP' to be and inline constant

Tags: groovy

I am using the TypeChecked annotation of Groovy and setting the value to `TypeCheckingMode.SKIP`

```
@TypeChecked(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)
static Object myMethod(Object value, String javaType) {
    ...
}
```

The above statement `'@TypeChecked(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)'` generates this error 
:

```
Expected 'TypeCheckingMode.SKIP' to be and inline constant
```

Thanks so much in advance for the help! :-)

Comment: Do you have an actual complete example script that shows the problem?

Comment: Dear tim_yates, thanks for your comment.
The error is shown as I add the '@TypeChecked(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)' and no matter what are next statements I write i.e.

@TypeChecked(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)
 public void demo() {
        int a;
 }

Also generates errors.

Comment: Right... 1: The code you pasted is not runnable by anyone else to verify your problem.  They would have to write extra code around it. 2: You don't show if or how you are setting type checking in your script outside of this. (if you're not, there's no point in what you're doing) 3: The error message has a spelling mistake in it, so I suspect it's not the real error message but rather something you have invented from memory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
@CompileStatic(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)
```